# Is there way to use Windows Easy Transfer on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, migration, windows-easy-transfer

At work, I'd been experimenting with using Windows Server 2008 as a desktop machine - I'm a s/w developer so some of the server software was particularly appropriate, but back in the day there was a suggestion that Server 2008 would be faster than Vista (mainly because of less bloat).

I'm now wanting to move across to a new Windows 7 workstation; not only does Server 2008 not have Windows Easy Transfer, but I can't attack the problem from the Windows 7 end either - when I try to run the migration wizard it claims that the software 'isnt compatible with this version of Windows'. I'd bet that it would work fine, if only it wasn't for the arbitrary version check...

Is there any way to coax this software into working?

If not, any good alternatives to Windows Easy Transfer - I don't fancy having to manually copy application settings etc across myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Easy Transfer is not functionnal under Windows 2008 Server. What I suggest to you os to use a third party software. There is 2 software that I'd use here they are:

[Norton Ghost:](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost) Best recovery/backup software that I've used so far. Works fine, works fast and no pain using it.

The second one is [Acronis.](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) Same thing as Norton Ghost, it's powerfull and the recovery process is really painless.

I don't know when or if Microsoft will make a functionnal version for servers but I hope since it's working really nice for workstations OS.

Hope this will help!

David.

Comment: Thanks David, but I've got access to plenty of backup solutions. The joy of Windows Easy Transfer was that it bundled up various application settings along with each user's documents, favourites etc...

I've started doing the process manually... it's not the end of the world, but it's slightly frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

You can put Windows Easy Transfer on Server 2008. This guide is for 64-bit systems only.

1. Download a zip file that I made from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c99m6jx65pe0y3h/WindowsVistaWindowsEasyTransferForServer2008x64Edition.zip?dl=0):
2. Copy the migwiz folder to the `system32` folder.
3. Run the `ApplicationVerifier.amd64.msi` file and set it up.
4. Launch `Application Verifier 4.0 x64` and do the following:
5. Go to the file menu and choose add application (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and browse to the `migwiz` folder that you put into `system32` earlier.
6. Select `migwiz.exe` and press *Open*.
7. There should be a shaded checkbox for *Basics*. Uncheck it by clicking on it.
8. Expand *Compatibility* (but do not check it), then check *HighVersionLie*. Right click on it and click *Properties*. Change *Product Type* to `1`.
9. Click Ok.
10. Click 'Save' and then 'Exit'.
11. Open up Windows Explorer, click on the address bar and type the following: `\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\System Tools` and you should end up in a hidden folder where the Start Menu shortcuts for *System Tools* are kept.
12. Copy the 'Windows Easy Transfer' or 'migwiz' (depending on which one you ended up with) shortcut to that folder.

Now you have Easy Transfer working on Server 2008.

Comment: The question is 9 years old... Anyway, you suggest to download a file from a dropbox share: this is not safe, because nobody should trust a file downloaded from a private share, and also you cannot grant that this share will exist forever.